# Can I use a loop inside a react hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Can i do this:

```
const [borderCountries, setBorderCountries] = useState([])
useEffect(() => {
    country.borders.forEach(c => {
        fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/${c}`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => setBorderCountries([...borderCountries,data.name]))
    })
}, [])
```

Country borders is a prop passed to the component. If not what can I do?

Comment: yeah you can but it doesnt mean you should.

Answer (score 5):

You can, but not quite like that, for a couple of reasons:

1. Each fetch operation will overwrite the results of the previous one, because you're using `borderCountries` directly rather than using the callback version of `setBorderCountries`.
2. Since the operation depends on the value of a prop, you need to list that prop in the `useEffect` dependencies array.

The minimal change is to use the callback version:

```
.then(data => setBorderCountries(borderCountries => [...borderCountries,data.name]))
//                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

...and add `country.borders` to the `useEffect` dependency array.

That will update your component's state *each time* a `fetch` completes.

Alternatively, gather up all of the changes and apply them at once:

```
Promise.all(
    country.borders.map(c =>
        fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/${c}`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => data.name)
    })
).then(names => {
    setBorderCountries(borderCountries => [...borderCountries, ...names]);
});
```

---

Either way, a couple of notes:

1. Your code is falling prey to a footgun in the `fetch` API: It only rejects its promise on *network* failure, not HTTP errors. Check the `ok` flag on the `response` object before calling `.json()` on it to see whether there was an HTTP error. More about that [in my blog post here](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html).
2. You should handle the possibility that the `fetch` fails (whether a network error or HTTP error). Nothing in your code is currently handling promise rejection. At a minimum, add a `.catch` that reports the error.
3. Since `country.borders` is a property, you may want to cancel any previous `fetch` operations that are still in progress, at least if the border it's fetching isn't still in the list.

Putting #1 and #2 together but leaving #3 as an exercise for the reader (not least because how/whether you handle that varies markedly depending on your use case, though for the cancellation part you'd use [`AbortController`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController)), if you want to update each time you get a result

```
const [borderCountries, setBorderCountries] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    country.borders.forEach(c => {
        fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/${c}`)
            .then(res => {
                if (!res.ok) {
                    throw new Error(`HTTP error ${res.status}`);
                }
                return res.json();
            })
            .then(data => setBorderCountries(borderCountries => [...borderCountries, data.name]))
            //                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            .catch(error => {
                // ...handle and/or report the error...
            });
    });
}, [country.borders]);
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Or for one update:

```
const [borderCountries, setBorderCountries] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    Promise.all(
        country.borders.map(c =>
            fetch(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/${c}`)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => data.name)
        })
    )
    .then(names => {
        setBorderCountries(borderCountries => [...borderCountries, ...names]);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // ...handle and/or report the error...
    });
}, [country.borders]);
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score -1):

You can but it's Not a good practice.